# fopen changes the value of array element in c

Tags: c

I am new to coding and learning file I/O operations in C. Piece of the code I'm trying is this:

```
void output(long *result){
    FILE *fp1 ;
    printf("**The result is=%ld\n",result[1]);
    fp1 = fopen ("output1.txt", "w+");
    printf("***The result is=%ld\n",result[1]);

    if ( fp1 == NULL )
    {
        puts ( "Cannot open output file" ) ;
        exit(0) ;
    }
    fprintf( fp1,"%ld",result[1]) ;
    fclose (fp1);
}
```

The function argument is being correctly transferred to function. But the outputs of `printf` statements before and after the `fopen` are different. I get:

```
**The result is=1714
***The result is=140734960430456
```

Can't understand the behavior. Please help. Went through previous discussions available on this, could not get help.

Comment: You must show the code that calls this function. Perhaps `result` is non-initialized.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, how is `output` being called?

Comment: Likely the integer pointer passed is unallocated. Please provide the complete code.

Comment: Do you get `result` from a function that returns the address of a local variable or a local array?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `result` is pointing somewhere where it shouldn't.

Comment: You returned a pointer to a stack local, didn't you!

Comment: @MOehm yeah! From main, I called a certain function blah() which returned me this array address 'res' .. I confirmed the correctness of resultant array, and passed it to the above function, by calling output(res) (res is a long array).

Comment: @Veena: You cannot return a local array. After the function returns, all local variables are invalidated. Access to invalidated arrays is undefined behaviour. There are several ways how to solve this: You could pass in a buffer and have the function fill that; you could allocate memory on the heap with `malloc` or you could use a static array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not with the `output` function, but with where you get the `result` array from. You probably have a function like this:

```
    int *range(int n)
    {
        int array[n];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = i;

        return array;
    }
```

where you return a local array. You shouldn't do that, because all automatic variables of `range` will be invalidated when execution returns from the function.

There are several ways to solve this:

#### Buffer as argument

The usual way to handle this is to pass a buffer in from the calling function and then have the function fill it:

```
    void range(int *array, int n)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = i;
    }
```

You can then create a range with:

```
    int R[10];

    range(R, 10);

    // use R
```

This is the usual approach. It has the advantage that the calling code must care about the allocation of the array. Here, an automatic array is used that will be cleaned up after the function returns.

#### Allocate memory

Another method is to allocate memory on the heap and return a handle to that array:

```
    int *range(int n)
    {
        int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array));  // TODO: Check for NULL
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = i;

        return array;
    }
```

You can then ceate a range with:

```
    int *R = range(1000);

    // use R

    free(R);
```

Because the memory was dynamically allocated, it must be released with `free` later. This method is suitable if you don't know in advance how big an array might be or if the array is very large, where allocating on the stack might lead to problems.

#### Static buffer

Another, not very common, method is to use a `static` array. This method might be useful in some cases, but has limited applicability, because the same static buffer is used for all calls.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You made my day! I tried both malloc and static and both ways are working. I would go for malloc. But could not understand one thing. How could malloc solve the problem? because it is also memory allocated to a local variable! which we return to main?! (sorry if the question is too lame.. i am at my start). Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You return the pointer which holds the address of the allocated memory. This pointer is returned as value, just as, for example, a number is returned as value. In your faulty example, you also return a pointer; the difference is that the memory that pointer points to isn't valid any longer. The allocated memory statys valid until you `free` it.